# how to parse json array in a json object response?

Tags: android, arrays, response

Iwant to access a jsonArray data in a jsonObjet response code that comes from server. here is my response json

```
{
    event_id: "32",
    event_title: "امیر",
    event_description: "تست امیر",
    event_image: "2_1550507094.jpg",
    event_hikers_amount: "9",
    event_private: "0",
    event_date_start: "17/2/2019",
    event_date_end: "21/2/2019",
    event_time_start: "21:54",
    event_time_end: "12:54",
    event_locations_array: 
        "[
            {"latitude":37.58728984572849,"longitude":45.10016608983278},
            {"latitude":37.57651702299841,"longitude":45.0880378112197},
            {"latitude":37.5753956777439,"longitude":45.1045374199748},         
            {"latitude":37.564077382844964,"longitude":45.094508975744255},
            {"latitude":37.55829758877768,"longitude":45.08105669170619},
            {"latitude":37.53919984571198,"longitude":45.09874418377876}
        ]",
    event_latitude_location: "37.587289845728",
    event_longitude_location: "45.100166089833",
    event_status: "1",
    event_users_id: "2"
}
```

I want to parse "event_locations_array" and what what i done :

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

                description = jsonObject.getString("event_description");
                people_joined = jsonObject.getString("event_hikers_amount");
                date_start = jsonObject.getString("event_date_start");
                date_end = jsonObject.getString("event_date_end");
                time_start = jsonObject.getString("event_time_start");
                time_end = jsonObject.getString("event_time_end");
                privacy = jsonObject.getString("event_private");

                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("event_locations_array");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject points = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject lat = points.getJSONObject("latitude");
                    JSONObject lang = points.getJSONObject("longitude");
                }

                setTextView();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

here i can't take that jsonArray. what i did wrong here let me know . I'm a little confused
thanks in advance

Comment: Please post the error message or log you got along with it. 
PS : It is better to use a combination of gson() library and POJO classes for the parsing. Manual parsing will consume more time and effort.

Comment: Please share your error,why you dont use GSON ? and i think you have just a json object why you use jsonArray?

Comment: @milad salimi I got this exeption "at event_locations_array of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Fast solution

If you can not change the JSON generation, simply use this code:

```java
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

try {
  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

  description = jsonObject.getString("event_description");
  people_joined = jsonObject.getString("event_hikers_amount");
  date_start = jsonObject.getString("event_date_start");
  date_end = jsonObject.getString("event_date_end");
  time_start = jsonObject.getString("event_time_start");
  time_end = jsonObject.getString("event_time_end");
  privacy = jsonObject.getString("event_private");

  // 1 - fix string to array conversion
  JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonObject.getString("event_locations_array"));
  for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject points = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    // 2 - the fields as double
    double lat = points.getDouble("latitude");
    double lang = points.getDouble("longitude");
  }

  setTextView();

  } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

#### Detailed solution

There are two errors:

1. The `event_locations_array` : `"[[{"latitude":37.58728984572849].."` contains a string. For the value that it's contains I think it must be generated as array (without the initial and final ")
2. After fix the first problem, you are trying to extract as object the properties `latitude` and `longitude`, but they are attributes. So change in your code:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject points = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
  JSONObject lat = points.getJSONObject("latitude");
  JSONObject lang = points.getJSONObject("longitude");
}
```

With

```java
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject points = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
  double lat = points.getDouble("latitude");
  double lang = points.getDouble("longitude");
}
```

Comment: I got this exeption "at event_locations_array of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray"

Comment: I update the answer. I suppose that you can change the JSON generation.

Comment: Ok, I put both situations: you can not change JSON generation, you can change JSON generation.

Answer (score 0):

To get Values of `event_locations_array` use following code:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("event_locations_array");
    for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String latitude = jsonObject.getString("latitude");
        String longitude = jsonObject.getString("longitude");
    }
```

Comment: I got this exeption "at event_locations_array of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray"